# Как уменьшить размер апк с 1мб до 100кб?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, gradle

В android-studio даже только что созданный проект весит 1.2мб. Очень нужно сжать апк до 100,хотя бы до 250кб. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это лучше сделать? в настройках поставил minifyEnable. Сжалось на половину. До 720. Надо еще. Как можно еще дожать его?

Вот использованные библиотеки:

```
dependencies {
releaseCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Хм...А вы пробовали, например, поставить targetSDK на маленькие значения? Не факт, что поможет, но вдруг...

Comment: Когда ставил tragetSDK на меньшие значения просто все ломалось. Студия сразу же начинала ругаться на нехватку большого количества файлов и на этом мои попытки закончились.

Comment: Скорее всего это произошло из-за использования библиотеки поддержки ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'). Чтобы от неё избавиться, надо все активити наследовать от класса `Activity` и убрать из стилей все её упоминания.

Comment: Вам нужно было писать в вопросе о том, что AppCompat вам не нужен, но без него все падает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Замените

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

на

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

А если юнит тестирование не используете, то вообще удалите.
В любом случае толку пихать это в apk нет никакого.

Answer (score 4):

- использовать обфускацию ProGuard
- удалить не используемые jar библиотеки
- удалить ненужные картинки
- по возможности использовать [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

**Update**

Еще можно поставить `minSdkVersion` более новой версии, размер апк может уменьшиться

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. По поводу proGuard все ясно. По поводу того, как правильно удалить jar и по поводу ненужных картинок не могли бы Вы поподробнее рассказать? Это нужно делать еще до сборки апк? или можно после, через apktool? И, если можно, по поводу 9patch не могли бы Вы поподробнее рассказать.

Comment: @lemuur Извините, не экстрасенс и не могу узнать какие библиотеку у вас использованы, приложите кусок, где показаны dependencies и файлы папки lib

Comment: Ниже написал dependencies. Папка libs пуста

Comment: Поставил более новую версию minSdk размер уменьшился на 2кб.(

Comment: @lemuur на сколько новую? Думаю 15 можно смело ставить.

Comment: 14 поставил. сейчас попробую 15 поставить.

Comment: поставил 15. Размер не уменьшился. 718кб как и был.

Answer (score 2):

Не использовать appCompat - использовать только стандартные либы андроида.